# angular 5 - Conditional CSS application - is there a simpler way?

Tags: angular

I am taking in JSON data and generating a material list from them with `mat-list` using the `*ngFor` directive.

I have also researched and found that using `[NgClass] = "{'CssClassName': condition}"` enables me to apply different CSS classes to each list entry 
 depending on any value of my choosing within the data itself.

However... I am changing the background style of each entry depending on their ID number, and I have 10 IDs making this `NgClass` section within the HTML rather long and difficult to read as you are not able to split this onto different lines...

*You can see below how long the actual line of code is - of course the text does wrap in my editor, but it still look horrendous - [Full code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/conditional-css-on-json-data)*

```
<mat-chip class="list-item" [ngClass] = "{'one':r.id === 1, 'two':r.id === 2,'three':r.id === 3, 'four':r.id === 4,'five':r.id === 5, 'six':r.id === 6,'seven':r.id === 7, 'eight':r.id === 8, 'nine':r.id === 9, 'ten':r.id === 10}">
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same outcome that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class are named "class1","class2","class3"... (not "one", "two","three"..) you can use

```
<mat-chip class="list-item" [ngClass]="'class'+r.id">
```

Comment: oh groovy! I didn't realise this could work. So much simpler than having to refactor all of my code XD

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function for that !

```
[ngClass]="createClassesObject(r)"
```

In your TS

```js
createClassesObject(r: any) {
  return {
    one: r.id === 1,
    two: r.id === 2,
    // You get the point
  };
}
```

**EDIT** You can even shorten the function (**[proof of work](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzpjcwp/)**) :

```js
indexes = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']; // etc.

createClassesObject(r: any) {
  return this.indexes.reduce((p, n) => {
    if (r.id === this.indexes.indexOf(n)) { p[n] = true; }
    return p;
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Makes a lot of technical sense, although I am going to accept @Eliseo's answer above, don't think I don't like or don't appreciate yours! :-)

Comment: No problem, I too upvoted his answer. It's much cleaner and easier !